# Angular 2 Custom Validator for Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

Can anyone please guide what is the proper way to implement custom validator for Reactive form if we are not using template driven forms at all?

I have gone through

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

and

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation

Both in the end create a directive, is it necessary? or can we do it without creating a directive?

I tried this:

```
//my-app.module.ts
export interface ValidationResult {
    [key: string]: boolean;
}

function personName(control: FormControl): ValidationResult {

        if (!control.value) {
            return null;
        }

        var valid = /^[a-zA-Z. ]*$/.test(control.value);

        if (valid) {
            return null;
        }
        return { "pattern": true };
    }


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        MyComponent
    ],
    exports: [
    ],
    providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: personName, multi: true }]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

But when I apply personName validator to my reactive form, and test it in browser I get below error in console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for personName!
```

Answer (score 1):

When using reactive forms, you don't need to `provide` your validators.  Instead, you attach them to the `formControl` objects when creating your form in your component. When using the Form Builder, this looks something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myform = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [undefined, personName],
  })
}
```